# Find persons with connection to other person

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm playing with Neo4J, and trying to find all persons who has a connection with a person.

What I want is to have a (p:Person) and the look at all relations, and follow them, until I find an other (p2:Person), and the return all (p2). There can be diffrent rutes from (p) to (p2). A couple of exampels would be:

```
(p:Person)-->(:Tweet)-[:mentions]->(p2:Person)
(p:Person)-->(:Tweet)-[:in_reply_to]->(:Tweet)-[:mentions](p2:Person)
(p:Person)-[:follows]->(p2:Person)
```

And a lot of other cases. More general, the point is, I want to follow a relation from (p:Person) until it finds a (p2:Person) or the node has no more outgoung, unused relations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this

```
(p:Person)-[:mentions|in_reply_to|mentions*1..5]->(p2:Person)
```

That would match all paths of length 1 to 5 matching those relationship types.  You can also take out the directionality if you don't care about that.  You'll probably want to assign it to a path variable and then return that, like this:

```
MATCH path=(p:Person)-[:mentions|in_reply_to|mentions*1..5]->(p2:Person)
RETURN path
```

If you want to find the shortest path between two people:

```
MATCH path=shortestPath((p:Person)-[:mentions|in_reply_to|mentions*1..5]->(p2:Person))
RETURN path
```

Comment: Also note the `allShortestPaths` function.  See here: http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-match.html#_shortest_path

Comment: Would neo4j run faster with shortestPath than without, if I just want to find a path between two users? or does it just make it slower? (If I look for all persons related to (p), and if it's a connection between two persons.)

Comment: That's a good question.  I'm not.  If I had to guess I'd say it's probably about the same because it still needs to look through all of the potential paths.  I'd suggest playing around with `EXPLAIN` and `PROFILE` to figure out how changing your query affects performance

Comment: In a quick test, it looks like using shortestPath is faster, as it filteres (p) in the beginning while it looks at all (:Person) * 2 (The (p) and (p2)) paths. This is however only a quick, small test.